# Is there a way to select one specify columns after joining?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

On my main entity class, I have this reference to another entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "OTHER_ENTITY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@Setter
private OtherEntity someEntity;
```

So, I can select two fields from this someEntity when I create my pojo/domain model from this entity. Is there a way to limit the selection above to just the two fields I need from OtherEntity or do I have to select the entire thing initially in memory first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use spring data projection

[Spring Data Projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

```
public interface MainEntityProjection{

      OtherEntityProjection getSomeEntity();

    interface OtherEntityProjection {
            String getName();
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To what purpose exactly? You have this entity with a reference to OtherEntity, which I would guess is the way the data actually is in the database. If you only ever want to associate 2 fields from OtherEntity when fetching an Entity.. don't map it like this. Make it a read-only (which you already have on the join column def) embeddeable that only has the two fields (and the OTHER_ENTITY_ID mapping if that isn't one of the two).

Note though that you then won't get identity or caching benefits, as this relationship and data will be independent of OtherEntity; you might be better off with lazy fetching on the basic and relation attributes in OtherEntity depending on the data, just so it can be reused for caching and to reduce the query overhead if OtherEntity is used in other spots in your application.